# Override definition of function passed by function argument

Tags: javascript, function, function-pointers

I have one function, how can I override definition of function which is passed as argument to function argument ?

[If I pass a function as argument to function connect. Is should override it's definition in global scope. ]

Following program does that by hard coding the function name. But problem with that approach is we are hard coding the function name. Is there a way to override without knowing function name ?

```
f1 = function () {
    console.log("f1");
}


connect = function () {
    var x = arguments;
    var oldClass = arguments[0]; // Copy original before overwriting
    f1 = function () {
        console.log("overwritten");
        oldClass.apply(this, arguments);
    };
    f1.prototype = oldClass.prototype;
}

connect(f1);
f1();
```

Problem with connect function is that we are hard coding the function name

```
connect2 = function () {
    var x = arguments;
    var oldClass = arguments[0]; // Copy original before overwriting
    arguments[0] = function () {
        console.log("overwritten");
        oldClass.apply(this, arguments);
    };
    arguments[0].prototype = oldClass.prototype;
}

connect2(f1);
f1();
```

Comment: What are you asking? Its really unclear.

Comment: @Brendan If I pass a function as argument to function connect. Is should override it's definition in global scope.

Comment: @VivekGoel Why are you replacing the prototype? And why are you calling the `oldClass`? What exactly are you trying to do? Overriding a function is your solution to a problem. But what is that actual problem?

Comment: Should it? I didn't think you could pass functions but I bet you could pass a variable equal to a function call.

Comment: @Brendan That was an interview question. So I don't have control of arguments.

Comment: It's impossible. You can only replace the reference to a function with a reference to a wrapped function. So now you only change the function reference in the first entry of the arguments array.

Comment: @TheShellfishMeme Any way I can extract function name and use eval to replace the function ?

Comment: It might be an anonymous function or not be in scope. So nope.

Comment: Personaly I think this was a question that should not be solved in the way it was ask, but where they tried to find out if you see the problems, asks the right questions about the code design, and after that beeing able to give a solution.